# How to read old Apple ][ 5.25" floppy disks

Tags: hardware, data-transfer, floppy

It's like Apple is a different company than it was when it produced the computer I'm talking about, so I'm not sure this is the intended topic of discussion here, but this *is* a question about Apple hardware, so here I go.

I have an old Franklin Ace 2100 Apple-compatible computer that I'm about to send off to a museum, but I also have a bunch of homemade software that they're not interested in and can't help me recover. Before I send this off I'd like to know that someday I might be able to get at that software again myself. I thought I once saw 5.25" USB floppy drives on Thinkgeek that might have been useful in such a data recovery process, but I can't find them any more. And even if I did, I know Apple 5.25" drives are incompatible with IBM/PC drives possibly at a hardware level, so I don't know if it would have been useful.

Can anyone help me figure out if there's a cost effective device for extracting the data from these old Apple ][ disks from the 1980s (they're almost all still functional - I just tried them yesterday again!)? I could elect to rely on a data recovery service, but then I would have to hold on to my system long enough to sort out what disks I want to recover data from before I send it away, so ideally, I'd like to be able to perform this recovery myself. My current system, BTW, is not from Apple (it's a "PC", and not an Apple-based one -- the term "PC" has always bothered me -- Apples were personal computers too).

Comment: Can you get a network card for the 2100 before you give it away? Then, of course, you can transfer the files to some more modern device. Nothing built in the last 25 years will accept an external 5.25" drive for these disks, even supposing you found the drive!

Comment: If I could get a network card, a whole new mess of questions or problems would come with it. I don't know that I have the software to access a network or to extract full disk images in a network portable format.

Comment: Some possibility of using Telnet or Kermit?

Comment: I don't have any communication software of any sort for this system. As far as **I** was aware there were not even modems let alone internet in 1985, at least not that I could use. There's not even a serial port on the computer. I doubt that the computer is going to be involved in my solution except to validate that the disks are good and possibly make copies of them if I don't want to mess with originals.

Comment: Yes, we had [modems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem) back in 1985, 1200 baud if you were wealthy. The deal back then was getting an add-on card with a modem port, and a floppy with telnet, ftp, or kermit. Some of those cards could also be used for primitive peer-to-peer file transfer, if you had a second, somewhat newer computer that used a storage medium that's still easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of work has been done in the retrocomputing community to allow transfer of 5 1/4" floppies in all the major 8-bit formats to virtual disk images that can be used on a modern computer via emulation software.  For example, [KryoFlux](http://webstore.kryoflux.com/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=28) is a hardware interface that uses generic (cheap) PC-style floppy drives to read any disk format, including Apple II.  This is kind of overkill for doing what you want, but how valuable are your old BASIC programs to you?  Memories are priceless...

Comment: KryoFlux is still priced at the "luxury" level for me to consider getting one for this purpose, but I have had some spare money in recently years and will probably spring for one in the not-too-distant future to recover my own software and possibly help others recover theirs if anybody else is in the same predicament.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this myself, but I did a little searching to see what might solve your problem.  Stumbled across this:

http://adtpro.sourceforge.net/

If you can connect to your modern computer using a serial cable (though even that's troublesome in this day and age…) this just might be your ticket.

Comment: I think this won't work for my case because I don't have a serial port. I have: Keyboard, Monitor, Game Controller, Parallel. I guess what would be cool is if there were some cable that could plug into the keyboard port and create the software on the Apple end by typing it in. Then I could use that software with another cable connection to transfer data back.

Comment: There are USB to serial converters

Comment: @Mark I'm fairly certain the asker meant a serial port on his Ace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into the hardware (floppy controller) available from deviceside.com at http://shop.deviceside.com/prod/FC5025
According to the details at http://www.deviceside.com/fc5025.html it appears to allow Windows 7 systems to read Apple DOS disks (among many others) via USB port. Unfortunately, they don't seem to sell the 5.25" drives that work with this controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering resorting to some optical data transfer. I don't think I have the time, motivation or expertise to transfer all the software this way (I'd have to be able to read disks at a binary level and format up something like QR codes for the transfer) but I thought maybe I could do program listings on files that are pure BASIC code. Here's a sample:

[image: Code listing screenshot]

Unfortunately I have not found an OCR program that will do a good job transforming this back to text. Any thoughts on simple adjustments I could employ or specific OCR software to use to make this work better?